# If $A \cap B \ne \varnothing$ do we have $\partial (A \cap B) = ( \partial A \cap B ) \cup ( A \cap \partial B)$?

Tags: general-topology

Assuming A and B is closed,
if $A \cap B \ne \varnothing$ do we have $\partial (A \cap B) = ( \partial A \cap B ) \cup ( A \cap \partial B)$ ?

If not, under what condition is there equality?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I drew a picture and tried to find some obvious counter-examples.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\partial (A \cap B) = (A \cap B) - O(A \cap B) = A \cap B - O(A) \cap O(B)$ where $O(S)$ is the interior of $S$. On the other hand, we have $\partial A \cap B = (A - O(A)) \cap B = A \cap B - O(A) \cap B$.

Then the right side evaluates to

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
(A \cap B - O(A) \cap B) \cup (A \cap B - A \cap O(B)) &= (A \cap B) - (O(A) \cap B \cap O(B) \cap B) \\
&= (A \cap B) - (O(A) \cap O(B))
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Using de Morgan's laws.

So the equality does hold. Interestingly, we don't use $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$ at all.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to also show that $O(A)\cap O(B) = O(A\cap B)$.

Comment: @AndrewShedlock That's always true. For we see that $O(A) \cap O(B) \subseteq A \cap B$. And suppose $U$ is an open set such that $U \subseteq A \cap B$. Then $U \subseteq A$ and $U \subseteq B$. Then $U \subseteq O(A)$ and $U \subseteq O(B)$. Then $U \subseteq O(A) \cap O(B)$.

Comment: @DoctorWho But if we take $A = \mathbb{Q}$ and $B = \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ it seems to me that equality doesn't hold ?